# Java Cannot initialize ArrayList variables in constructor

Tags: java, oop, variables, arraylist, constructor

I have several different types of ArrayLists.

Each stores split data from a .csv file.

```
//NOTE: this is for understanding, syntax may not be correct.
ArrayList<String> name = {item1, item2, item3, item4};
ArrayList<String> type = {type1, type2, type3, type4};
ArrayList<Double> price = {price1, price2, price3, price4};
ArrayList<Integer> qty = {qty1, qty2, qty3, qty4};
```

In my Item class I have a constructor like so,

```
public Items(String t, String n, Double p, Integer q){
    type = t; //type mismatch : cannot convert from String to ArrayList<String>
    name = n;//type mismatch : cannot convert from String to ArrayList<String>
    price = p;//type mismatch : cannot convert from Double to ArrayList<Double>
    qty = q;//type mismatch : cannot convert from Integer to ArrayList<Integer>
}
```

As you can see, I cant initialize my constructor because of different types. However, in my main method I call each variable as so,

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    ArrayList<Items> itm = new ArrayList<Items>();
    Items general = new Items();

    //place each item into object itm
    for(int i = 0; general.name.size(); i++)
    {
        itm.add(new Items(general.type.get(i), general.name.get(i), general.price.get(i); general.qty.get(i)));
    } //throws no syntax errors
```

If I put "general.name.get(i)" for example, wouldn't Java see that as a String and not an ArrayList? How do I initialize these variables in my constructor?

EDIT: When I use general.type.get(i); I want that index from ArrayList type to equal t in the constructor. This is the same for n, p, and q.

```
t = general.type.get(i);
```

Comment: We can't answer your question because we have no idea what `Items` is or what it's supposed to do. It appears that its `type`, `name`, `price`, and `qty` fields are all ArrayLists of values, yet the parameters of the constructor are typed as only single values

Comment: I see the confusion, I'll edit now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to initialize an ArrayList as String. If you tell what you really want to achieve, I can edit the code to do so.

**Item Class**

```
public class Item {
    public static ArrayList<String> type_list = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<String> name_list = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<Double> price_list = new ArrayList<>();
    public static ArrayList<Integer> qty_list = new ArrayList<>();

    public String type;
    public String name;
    public Double price;
    public Integer qty;

    public Item (String type, String name, Double price, Integer qty){
        this.type = type;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.qty = qty;
    }
}
```

**Main Class**

public static void main(String args[]){
    ArrayList items_list = new ArrayList<>();

```
Item.type_list.add("type1");
Item.type_list.add("type2");
Item.type_list.add("type3");
Item.type_list.add("type4");

Item.name_list.add("name1");
Item.name_list.add("name2");
Item.name_list.add("name3");
Item.name_list.add("name4");

Item.price_list.add(price1);
Item.price_list.add(price2);
Item.price_list.add(price3);
Item.price_list.add(price4);

Item.qty_list.add(qty1);
Item.qty_list.add(qty2);
Item.qty_list.add(qty3);
Item.qty_list.add(qty4);

for(int i = 0; i < Item.type_list.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(.....);
}
```

}

Comment: you figured out what I was trying to achieve. I was trying to take each element from the different ArrayLists and call them into the constructor. My end goal is to make 4 different objects that store the (type,name,price,qty) of an Item so I can sort them by type. I know I'm a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

A box for eggs ... is not an egg.

A list of strings ... is not a string.

Meaning: you can't create a list of strings directly from that single string. You can only **add** a string into a already existing list. Like putting an egg in your egg-box.

You need:

```
type = new ArrayList<>();
type.add(t);
```

for example; or shorter using that little helper method:

```
type = Arrays.asList(t);
```

And your other code with items is working because `general.type.get(i)` returns a single String object; and that is exactly what your Item constructor expects - a single string object.